# External input to Python program during runtime

Tags: python, batch-file, input

I am creating a test automation which uses an application without any interfaces. However, The application calls a batch script when it changes modes, and I am therefore am able to catch the mode transitions.

What I want to do is to get the batch script to give an input to my python script (I have a state machine running in python) during runtime. Such that I can monitor the state of the application with python instead of the batch file.

I am using a similar state machine to the one of Karn Saheb:
https://dev.to/karn/building-a-simple-state-machine-in-python

However, instead of changing states statically like:

```
device.on_event('event')
```

I want the python script to do something similar to:

```
while(True):
    device.on_event(input()) # where the input is passed from the batch script:

REM state.bat
set CurrentState=%1
"magic code to pass CurrentState to python input()" %CurrentState%
```

I see that a solution would be to start the python script from the batch file every time it is called with the "event" and then save the current event in another file upon termination of the python script... But I want to avoid such handling and rather evaluate this during runtime.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I find the setup hard to understand.  Maybe you can provide an [mcve] which mocks the real stuff to explain the situation better?

Comment: Hi Alfe,
The simplified idea is that I have this "black box" (No interface) program that I start using normal shell commands through python. I want to monitor how far along in the process this black box is, (it does compile tests, static code analysis, target testing, and in the end generates a report). When I start this black box from python I don't know when it is done testing, since there is no feedback. However, when changing from one test to another, e.g. static code analysis to generate a report, it calls a .bat file withthe  "Report" argument.

Comment: I want to edit this .bat file such that I can pass along the "Report" argument to my python state machine. The state machine would then know which state the "black box" is in (currently testing). I just dont know how to pass this argument from the .bat file to a running python program. Hope this is more understandable! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonably portable way of doing this without ugly polling on temporary files is to use a socket: have the main process `listen` and have the batch file(s) start a small program that connects to the server and writes a message.

There are security considerations here: you can start by listening only to the loopback interface, with further authentication if the local machine should not be trusted.

If you have more than one of these processes, or if you need to handle the child dying before it issues its next report, you’ll have to use threads or something like `select` to unify the news from different input channels (*e.g.*, waiting on the child to exit *vs.* waiting on news from the next batch file).

Comment: I like this idea! I bit more complex than what I was looking for, however, I want to avoid as you say "polling temp files". I am spawning anywhere from 1-10 of these black box processes, but if the main process is able to listen to multiple sockets/clients then I can differ from the processes based on the PID or execution path. I will search for some other solutions as well but this seems like a good option. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this solution now and it seems to be working just fine. I have a server that manages state machines for each "black box" that are starting or changing state. I had the server run as a standalone module, not to interfere with the main program such that I can continue with other stuff while the tests are running. The main program has a client that requests all active state machines and their states. Thank you for the idea :)

Comment: @Smule: Technically, you _listen_ only on the one server socket, but of course you can _accept_ several regular sockets that it creates.

Comment: True, I saw that when implementing it. I don't know how the server reacts to two simultaneous connections to the same socket. However, I have added a small timer around the socket.connect in order to retry in case of "ConnectionRefusedError". So hopefully I manage to reconnect when the socket is closed or available for new communication.

Comment: @Smule: There’s nothing wrong with multiple simultaneous connection attempts.  The call to `listen` specifies how many pending connections the kernel will hold for you until you `accept` them.

Comment: I am running `sock.listen(1)` for the TCP/IP socket. Then `while True:` I accept at each iteration and `try` to `.recv()` from the accepted connection. If I increase the `listen` value, will the `accept` still work for a single connection, meaning the `listen` value work as a watermark. Or will it restrict until amount of listen is met?

Comment: @Smule: It’s a limit—a feature to let you refuse connections that arrive faster than you can process (especially if, for simplicity, you serve one request completely before accepting the next, with no latency hiding).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Davis! Should be no problem to increase the limit for my use case then :)